# Excel php chart generation

Tags: php, image, excel, insert, charts

I am using PHPExcel library to read/write excel files. Now I want to generate a chart, or add an image (chart generated with [pChart](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/) ). I would like to know if there are other libraries that support dinamic image insertion (not template images) or chart generation based on written data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your only PHP options at present to work with charts in Excel are:

- To use PHP's [COM extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) with a copy of MS Excel itself on the server.
- Ilia Alshanetsky's [Excel extension<](http://ilia.ws/archives/222-PHP-Excel-Extension.html) (xls only, and requires a commercial component).
- The PHP wrapper around Open Office's alternative to COM ([PUNO](http://www.wstech2.net/index.php?do=0a,01,05)) (requires Open Office installed on the server with Java support enabled).

all of which use an external component for handling the excel data itself.

Reading and Writing charts is targeted for the next realease of PHPExcel (sometime between now and the end of June) for Excel 2007 (.xlsx) files, and in the following release (sometime around September) for BIFF (.xls) files

Comment: thank you, until the new release of PHPExcel i`ll just generate a Word file and a chart image and integrate the image in a .docx, there is a library in which you can add images. I was thinking if someone edits the generated excel file (after "download") the chart updates to the changed values. Thanks for the prompt info

Comment: Note that you can add images to a worksheet now using PHPExcel (but images of a chart won't update when the underlying data is updated)... it's specifically adding charts that will be a major new feature in the 1.7.7 release